# How to assign Compact LayoutTypes to Lightning:recordForm Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience, salesforcedx

I am using the new [lightning recordForm component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation)

I try to assign the layoutType to be Compact.I created a new compact layout called Cash that is assigned to the cash recordtype. However, It still uses the primary page layout that is assigned to the cash recordtype.

```
<lightning:recordForm aura:id="recordForm" objectApiName="financials__c"
                recordTypeId="{!v.recordTypeId}" onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}" onsubmit="{!c.handleAccountSubmit}" layoutType="Compact"
                mode="edit" />
```